# Not able to add Tippy for a button in react js

Tags: reactjs, tippyjs

I have imported below packages and I tried referring to the below link, which I did not understand where to place tippy code. Please help me.

https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/html-content

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import tippy from 'tippy.js';
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';

class Trial extentds Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.submitTaggedFace} disabled={!this.validate()} variant="contained" color="primary"
                data-tippy="Tooltip"
                data-tippy-animation="scale"
                data-tippy-duration="0"
                data-tippy-arrow="true"
                data-tippy-delay="[800, 200]"
                >Click to Tag</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create demo of it in stackblitz?

Comment: Are you using this? https://github.com/tvkhoa/react-tippy

Comment: No, I have used "npm i tippy.js" to install package and imported the package and tried using it. @Colin

Comment: It'll be easier if you use the React library.

Comment: Still the tooltip is not coming @Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You must be missing something in other component.

I have created this codesandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/5y8zm52own

Comment: I am also importing metirial-ui link, is that the reason which I am not gettting?

Comment: Here is the link I am importing 
"import { Grid, Card, CardHeader,  IconButton,  CardContent, Button, Checkbox, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';"

Comment: Yeah, but when I combine it with my code, it is not working. I am using cardcontent, cards from the meterial-ui

Comment: Can you post the code of your whole component where you are using this?

Comment: It is a very big component, which I can't post here

Comment: I created a new app, and copy pasted the same code which is there in your link still getting error

Comment: Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').

Comment: You can directly download it form codesandbox @PrajnaHegde .

Comment: And then `npm install` and `npm start`

Comment: okay, I have a doubt, here import tippy from "tippy.js"; is not at all used in the code, then why we have to import?

Comment: We need that bcoz there is some javascript function being executed with data-tippy attribute to show the tooltip.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use the code in followed link in react? https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@0.2.6/docs/index.html @Harish Soni

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/5y8zm52own check this sandbox you will get the idea on how to do it in react.

Comment: Cool No Problem glad to help. I think you wanted to learn more? there was a comment I guess

Comment: You can find me on Facebook sorry but cannot disclose my email here. You can find me with the same username.

Comment: I think I found you I dropped a msg if it's you can you please make a reply?

Comment: If I want to add content with image in the hover pop-up? How can I add?